# HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error

Tags: rest, groovy

Weirdest thing I have seen in a while. I run my API call through `Postman` and have no problems at all making a `GET` request. However, the groovy code below pulls `groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error`. I am not able to pull even debug to understand if I am actually getting a 5xx error or my code is legitimately broken.

Additionally I have had code like this work in the past, I re-pulled that working code and have the same error. Curious if my `Maven` config settings would be causing the issue as well (Not sure where I would have to debug). I have also tried messing with the URIbuilder line to see if changing the endpoints would help.

Thanks for helping

```
abstract class HTTTPClient {

protected runGetRequest(String endpointPassedIn, RESTClient Client){

    URIBuilder myEndpoint = new URIBuilder(new URI(Client.uri.toString() + endpointPassedIn))
    //Error happens at the next Line
    Client.get(uri: myEndpoint, contentType: ContentType.JSON)
    LazyMap Response = unprocessedResponse.getData() as LazyMap
    return Response
    }
}




@Singleton(lazy = true)
class RequestService extends HTTTPClient {

private String auth = "myAuth"
private String baseURL = 'https://api.endpoint.net/'

private RESTClient client = setClient(baseURL, auth)

public buildResponseList(int pagesToPull) {
    String endpoint = 'site/address.json?page='
    ArrayList responseList = []
    for (int i = 1; i <= pagesToPull; i++) {
        LazyMap Response = runGetRequest(endpoint + i, client)
        for (row in Response) {
            responseList.add(row)
            //TODO Add in items call here
        }
    }
    return conversationList
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to encoding in the Authorization, was on the server side, not the code side